# Override Activity from Android Library project

Tags: android, android-activity, android-library

I have an Android project.  Now I need to create a second edition of that project.

**What will differ:**

New edition of the Project should have different content in one of the Activities.

I was thinking about creating a library project and two new projects(`project1` and `project2`) which will use library project, but I don't really understand how to setup this.

Should I just convert the original project into library, then create two new projects and *then what*? How to make `project1` use `activity1` and `project2` use `activity2` in  the same place?

**EDIT**

What I've set up so far:

**MainProject, a library** has MainActivity.java and ChildActivity.java

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mainproject">
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChildActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

**StandAloneProject:** it has only ChildActivity.java

---

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.standaloneproject">
    <application>
        <activity
             android:name="com.example.mainproject.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChildActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**What I expect:**

When I launch StandAloneProject and click button, I want ChildActivity from StandAloneProject(not from MainProject) to be launched.

**What I get:**

When I launch StandAloneProject, I see MainActivity from MainProject, click button and get:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.standaloneproject/com.example.mainproject.ChildActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Comment: Ah, don't really know. I guess no, just the basic Eclipse Android template.

Comment: are you trying to create 2 versions of the same Android app?

Comment: Yes. And they will differ in the content of one of the activities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is how you start the child activity in MainActivity.java.
You need to 'manually' make sure that the correct ChildActivity is started.

One way to do this is to explicitly set the component for the intent.  The Context.getPackageName() function returns the package name of the application you are running in and you can use this to identify the 'correct instance' of ChildActivity you want to start.  Try this in your *onClick()* handler in MainActivity.java:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();       
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".ChildActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Old answer but i couldn't find a better one well over 3 years later.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is the correct one.

1. Create your library project.
2. Create a new project, create the activity that you need and add your library project to it.
3. Copy the AndroidManifest.xml from your library project into your new project but point the activity that differs to the projects activity instead of the activity in the library project.

Comment: I mean, my library project won't be aware of Activities in other projects. How can I leave that logic in the library project?

Comment: By quick fix I meant you copy the MyActivity class into your new project and in the new project you refer (in the manifest) to the new MyActivity class instead of the one in the library. The library will still read the old MyActivity class.

Comment: How do did you point to your library project for the standalone projects manifest? you need to point all library activities with the full package name name="com.your.libary.projects.packagename.youractivity"

Comment: android:name="com.example.mainproject.MainActivity"> here it is. And child project shows Activity from library project. But it fails to find its own activity.

Comment: If you copied the project maybe it has the wrong imports. Try remove/readd all imports of the activity

Comment: Is there a way to use Manifest Merge to simply replace the library's activity with that of the child project?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Set up a library project and two standard android projects which include the lib project.
Remember to copy your manifest activitys to the new projects. When you want to separate the activitys, you can extend the ones from your lib project. project1: MyActivty extends Activit1 .. project 2 MyActivit

Comment: A quckfix would be to just replace the activity launching the intent swell. :)

Comment: I try to clear something out. The library project has no reference to the other projects. Project1 and Project2 are including the library project (like including a jar). If you want a different behavior of your activitys from your library project, you have to extend the targeted activity inside the project from the library project and overwrite the methods that differ.