# Library project Dx UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION or ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools, dx

I have library project and regular android project which uses it.

**Library project:**

**src folder** package *com.myproject*

```
MainActivity
ChildActivity
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.project.library">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
        <application>
            <activity android:name="com.myproject.MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.myproject.ChildActivity">
            </activity>
        </application>
 </manifest>
```

**Standalone project**(is an Android project and uses library project):

**src folder** package *com.myproject*

```
ChildActivity
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.project">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
        <application>
            <activity android:name="com.myproject.MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.myproject.ChildActivity">
            </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

**What I want to achieve:**

ChildActivity from Android project should override ChildActivity from library project.

Compilation fails:

```
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/myproject/ChildActivity;
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:135)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:191)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:123)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:191)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:123)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:191)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:123)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:191)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:123)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:180)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:703)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:577)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1000)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-10-16 20:02:02 - Standalone] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

If I change src folder in Standalone project to com.myproject.standalone and change manifest entry to

```
<activity android:name="com.myproject.standalone.ChildActivity">
```

I got exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
```

Comment: I guess the you need to set a diffrent class name in `Stand Alone Project`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem I updated the question, changing package leads to exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare an activity in both manifests. pick one and use it. I prefer using the app manifest for all activity declarations.

Update: Also, a library project should NEVER EVER contain references to any project that references it. That is called circular dependency.

Update: So your code is a little confusing, but it looks like you are declaring classes with the same fully qualified name in both the library and standalone projects. This won't work. They need to have different qualified names. The qualified name is the full package and class name. Your AndroidManifest for the library declares the package as "com.myproject.library" but then declares 2 activities with the package "com.myproject". If they are in the library project, change the qualified name to "com.myproject.library.ActivityName" or use the ".ActivityName" shorthand. If they are in the same package, they need to be in a different package.

Comment: Is there circular dependency in what I've posted?

Comment: Removing activity declaration from one of the manifests didn't help.

Comment: the circular dependency comes from the child manifest declaring "com.myproject.Activity" in the package "com.myproject.library".

Comment: Thanks for your updates, but I already tried that. Here's my another question on the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683697/how-do-i-split-my-project-in-two-versions